# road extraction in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink, kinematics

[Simulink Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOLrA.png)

I want to extract a part of a road from a map and import it in MATLAB as a script function,

i tried using Driving scenario design toolbox:

Got the road from the OpenStreetMap, extracted the file, imported it to the enter image description here and then, clicked on export> MATLAB function, and then added a data extraction function.

this method didn't work, knowing that my aim is to get the Cartesian coordinates of the road (X,Y).

the reason why i need this road, is to use the (x,y) path as in my  kinematic bicycle model (Simulink model is given above).